# webgrid = how to build dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

How do i loop through a list of objects  and display each one at a column in a grid? 
for example, i want to do something like:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    tablestyle:="gridStyle",
    headerStyle:="headstyle",
    alternatingRowStyle:="alt",
    columns:=Grid.Columns(
        grid.column("column1", header:="Column1"),

        // This is where I want to do something like:

        for each entry in ListOfObjects
            grid.column(entry.ItemA, header:="ItemA")
        next
```

Comment: Are you sure this is really what you want to do? If ListOfObjects has 100 items, you'll end up with 101 columns in your table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is really what you want, but it's what you asked for:

```
@{
    List<WebGridColumn> cols = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    cols.Add(grid.Column("column1", header: "Column1"));
    foreach(var entry in ListOfObjects)
    {
        cols.Add(grid.Column(entry.ItemA, header: "ItemA"));
    }
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    tablestyle: "gridStyle",
    headerStyle: "headstyle",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt-alt",
    columns: cols
)
```